# set image size to full screen in android

Tags: android, image

I'm having an android app in which I'm taking a picture using the android camera.
This picture is taken in the `activity A` and after that is sent to `activity B` where is edited.

This is how I receive my image in `activity B`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        byte[] imageData = extras.getByteArray("imageData");
        Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData , 0, imageData.length,options);

        Matrix mat=new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);
        bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight(), mat, true); 
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myPic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapResult);
```

As you can see I'm rotating the `bitmap` I receive with 90 using this:

```
Matrix mat=new Matrix();
            mat.postRotate(90);
```

And here is my `imageView` in xml file:

```
<ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/myPic"
    />
```

The problem that I'm facing is that my picture is not full screen...it's almoust full screnn but not entirly.As you can see here:

[image]

If you could help me to increase a little bit its size I would really apreciate it.Thanks

EDIT:I wanna increase the width of my image only.Sorry!!

Comment: means that you want to show image behind button too....and buttons over it??

Comment: I wanna increase the width of the image that's all!

Comment: Have you tried android:scaleType="fitXY" in imageView xml?

Comment: I think the layout in which imageview is placed don't have layout_width="fill_parent"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have to crop the image. Because the image is not at its full height, the width of the image is proportionately scaled down, hence the black strips at the sides.

To be more specific, images taken using the phone's camera are probably intended to fit the screen exactly i.e. width-height ratio of image = width-height ratio of the screen. However, in your app the height of the image is constrained by the buttons at the top, so in order to maintain the width-height ratio of the image, the width of the image is scaled down proportionately.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean!Could you be more specific...and I wanna increase only the width of my image....that's all!

Comment: Suppose the image is 1000 x 2000, and the screen is 500 x 1000. Then, suppose your buttons are 100px tall. That means that the height of the image displayed = 1000 - 100 = 900. In order to maintain the ratio, the width of the image displayed = 900/2000 * 1000 = 450.

Comment: So, to increase the width of your image, either: 1) crop the top of your image by 200px (then width of image displayed = 900/1800 * 1000 = 500; 2) overlap the buttons over your image; 3) use [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) to scale and crop automatically.

Comment: To use setScaleType, use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

```
ImageView.ScaleType="CENTER_CROP"
```

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29)

You could use `CENTER_CROP` to get full screen image and maintain the image's aspect ratio.